# Find the minimal polynomial of a particular matrix

Tags: matrices, minimal-polynomials

Find the minimal polynomial of $A=\begin{pmatrix} 0  &0 & 0 &1\\  1 & 0 & 0&0\\  0 &1 &0 &0\\  0 &0  & 1&0\end{pmatrix}$

Since this is a square matrix, the minimal polynmial will be such that $p(A)=0$. How do I find such a polynomial?

Comment: That's not a square matrix, it's $5 \times 4$.  And it's not lower triangular either.

Comment: **Hint:** This is a permutation matrix

Comment: $\phantom{}$ $A^4 = I$.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio thank you for the observation, can you explain how I can use that fact?

Comment: @grayQuant: In addition to Jack's point, compute $A^n$ for $0\le n\le 3$ and observe that no two of them has a nonzero element in the same position -- so they are certainly linearly independent.

Answer (score 2):

Note the eigenvalues of $A$ are $\pm 1,\pm i$, each of which has the multiplicity 1. So the minimal polynomial is just the characteristic polynomial $p(x)=x^4-1$.